# Python convention for sub-delimiter

Tags: python, string, split

I am writing a script which takes a string as input and splits it into a list using the .split(sep = ',') function. Then, some of the items in the list will be split into sub-lists. For example:

```
    input = 'my,string,1|2|3'
    mylist = input.split(',')
    mylist[2] = mylist[2].split('|')
    print(mylist)
    > ['my','string',['1','2','3']]
```

The code works without a problem. (I know which position in the list will have the sub-list.) My question is: Is there any convention in python for which delimiter should be used to separate a string which will eventually be converted to numbers (int or float). Assuming that ',' is already used as the first delimiter?

As the programmer, I can request the string to be formatted using whichever delimiters I like. But I will have many users, so if there is a convention for separating numerical values, I would like to follow it. Note that the numbers may be float values, so I do not want to use the characters 'hyphen' or 'period' as delimiters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I should preface this by saying I have never heard of such a convention, but I like the question. The convention for nested lists in English is to use commas for the inner list and semi-colons for the outer list, e.g.:

> I have eaten: eggs, bacon, and apple for breakfast; toast, tuna, and a
>   banana for lunch; and chicken, salad, and potatoes for dinner.

That convention suggests `input = 'my;string;1,2,3;'`.

I also like the idea of using newlines: `input = 'my\nstring\n1,2,3\n'`. It has the benefit of being easy to read from / write to CSV.

Comment: Thanks! I had never heard of a convention either, but I thought it worth checking. I do like the newline '\n' idea (it naturally leads to array-style formatting), but in my application I'm reading the string as a line from a .csv file. In effect, I have triple-nested lists (I'm really using 3 different delimiters)!